# Python - Validation of an integer - except or except ValueError?

Tags: python

I've created the following test in Python 3.x:

```
answer = int(input("What's 5 x 8?"))
if answer == 40:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

answer = int(input("What's 4 + 7?"))
if answer == 11:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

answer = int(input("What's 9 - 4?"))
if answer == 5:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

but I don't know whether I should use `except` or `except ValueError` to validate each answer.

Using `except`:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("What's 5 x 8?"))
        if answer == 40:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
        break
    except:
        print("That's not a valid answer. Enter an integer.")
#This would be repeated for the two other questions
```

Using `except ValueError`:

```
while True:
    try:
        answer = int(input("What's 5 x 8?"))
        if answer == 40:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a valid answer. Please enter an integer.")
#This would be repeated for the two other questions
```

I only want integers to be accepted (e.g. '400', '3', etc.). Which one is better to use in my case?

Comment: Do you really want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit` and `ProcessorBurningError`?

Comment: *always* use the strictest exception handling possible. Note that requirements for "application not crashing" may require more loose exception handling, but probably not.

Comment: I find the code conceptually wrong, because 40.9 is also considered correct.

Comment: @timgeb -- I'm going to start off all my projects defining a `ProcessBurningError` exception from now on.

Comment: Sorry, my comment is wrong, I ran it with python2, where `raw_input` should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bare `except` is pretty much never the right thing, so you probably want to be catching the `ValueError`.

The problem with bare `except` is that it'll catch *anything* including things like `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, etc.  Even if you become a little more restrictive and do:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    ...
```

You can still end up glossing over all sorts of programming errors (e.g. if you accidentally misspelled an attribute and the code was raising `AttributeError` -- You'd be catching that exception and tracking down the resulting bugs would be harder).

My rule is to *only catch exceptions if you know how to handle them*.  In this case, you know how to handle a `ValueError` from that block of code, but you don't know how to handle `TypeError`, or `AttributeError` or pretty much anything else.  So, you should handle the `ValueError` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate for integer, you should go for ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use bare `except` in the context you want to catch the exception. If you want to catch all kinds of exception *not related to program exit*, which is true for most of the cases, use `except Exception`. But it is always a good idea to be specific.

And in the while loop you are `break`ing out abruptly. If you want to break out only when the correct answer is recieved, then:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("8 + 21 :"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a valid number")
    else:
        if x == 29:
            break
        else:
            continue  # this is not required, just being explicit
```

See if it works.